# Socket.io dilemma with clients.length (where clients === io.sockets.clients();)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Normally, when I send some JSON from one client to another, it works fine.  But if there is only one client, it still sends packets.  My solution was to (on the server-side, in node.js):

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients();

if(clients.length > 1){
// send stuff to other client
}
```

But when I do that, something extraordinarily strange occurs.  I'll open up a client, start instigating the actions during the if statement, and the console, which prints the JSON before sending it, does nothing, because there is only one client.  When I open up another client and instigate the actions during the if statement, the console will print out the JSON and send it to my other client.  However, if I go over to my first client that I opened and instigate the actions in the if statement, the console won't print anything out, and it won't send anything.  Why?  I tried changing the if statement to say:

```
if("hello" === "hello"){
// do the same stuff as before
}
```

and both clients could send JSON to one another, but because I had changed the if statement, with one client open I would still send useless packets.  For obvious reasons, the optimal situation would be if it wouldn't send packets with one client, but would send packets properly with more than one.

I hope that was clear, I'm sorry if that wasn't.

If I need to, I'll post more code.

**EDIT**:

Here is the code that updates the array:

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients();

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
clients.length++;
socket.on("disconnect", function() {
clients.length--;
console.log(clients.length + " clients are connected");
});
console.log(clients.length + " clients are connected");
});
```

Comment: but this only happens if I open up the first client once.  to clarify, if you refresh the first client after opening the second client, then it will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done any note.js lately, maybe this is bogus. But I thought: maybe the clients variable is defined for each client when he connects, and not updated later on. This seems the logic thing to me. I think that what you need to do is: fire an event to all clients when a new client connects, and update the "clients" variable.

Comment: I think @freakishs answer makes more sense than mine. I was thinking of separate instances of the clients var, but there's only one instance, probably.

Comment: there is only one instance, because it's all on the server, but his answer doesn't work, sadly.  I think it has to do with the if statement.

Comment: I figured. There are systems that do attempt to keep a set of data for each user though, old versions of ASP for example, that's why I thought it might have been relevant. But nodejs is obviously way too cool for such silliness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your code works (what's this: `clients.length++` ?? Incrementation of array's length??) but try doing this the "normal" way:

```
var clients;

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  clients = io.sockets.clients();
  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
      clients = io.sockets.clients();
      console.log(clients.length + " clients are connected");
  });
  console.log(clients.length + " clients are connected");
});
```

or even better (without holding global reference to connected users):

```
function get_clients() {
  var clients = io.sockets.clients();
  console.log(clients.length + " clients are connected");
}

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    get_clients();
  });
  get_clients();
});
```

Because `io.sockets.clients()` returns the array of all connected clients at the moment of calling it (perhaps that's why you get this strange behaviour).

Comment: yes, but when I put that in the if statement, I still had that problem :(

Comment: Can you make each client request the value of io.sockets.clients().length when a new client connects? That might help to make sure the server is working with the correct numbers.

Comment: @Matt Can you write down exactly how you use if statement?

Comment: I say "if (clients.length > 1) { // send data to other clients }"  I isolated the problem, and it's definitely the if statement.  It's nothing fancy, just simple emit and on events within the if statement

Comment: @Matt But what is `clients` and where you define it? It seems that you hold the reference to `clients` defined on `connection` event. But in this scenario each user sees clients connected only before him. You need to define `clients` variable on every event.

Comment: I defined clients before I made the connection event

Comment: @Matt Then it is wrong. :) You need to redefine the variable on every event. Please read once again everything I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you only use pure JS, but if you coding in React and TS, you might put "connection" and "disconnect" into an useEffect